# How can I find the Maximum of Polynomial Trendline?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a XY chart.
I used a polynomial trendline, now I need to find the maximum of the chart in an automatic way.

Is it possible?

Here is a picture to show the type of chart.

[image]

Comment: Do you need to know **where** the maximum is or **what** the maximum is ??

Comment: With only five points, if it takes a 4th order polynomial to fit them, the curve could potentially be "unusual".  If you have an actual data point at the apparent maximum, you could simply identify that point.  If such a trendline finds a peak between two points, that maximum it likely to be an artifact, or at least unreliable.

Comment: I need to know the maximum value achieved by the trendline. Is there a way to find it?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your picture, it seems that you have very few points and finding the largest of them is not enough.

The trendline generated automatically by Excel only draws the line and prints the calculated coefficients. To do something with the coefficients, you will have to calculate them yourself. Use the [LINEST](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/LINEST-function-84d7d0d9-6e50-4101-977a-fa7abf772b6d) function which calculates a linear regression. It's an array function which means that you select several cells, enter the formula and press Ctrl+Shift+Enter to enter it simultaneously into all cells. The formula calculates the linear least squares regression and fills all selected cells simultaneously.

[image: Excel screenshot]

Now that you have the coefficients you can calculate the maximum. Though, to find the maximum of a fourth-order polynomial, you will have to solve a cubic equation [which is not that easy.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubicFormula.html)

A possible approximation is to calculate the trendline values for many X values in some predefined range (my green line) and then to select the largest one using the MAX function (or, since the fourth-order polynomial's tails can rise high, by comparing each value with its neighbors).